# Downloading a picture with http get only downloads a small part of it

Tags: c++, http, winsock

I am trying to use the http protocol GET to ask the server to send me a picture. It compiles and will ask for the picture but the server only will send me a small part of it.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

using namespace std;

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
void die_with_error(char *errorMessage);
void die_with_wserror(char *errorMessage);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
string request;
string response;
int resp_leng;

char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
int sock;

WSADATA wsaData;
char *ipaddress = "210.125.167.240";
int port = 80;

//http://cwc.ghc.ac.kr/skin/base/board/view_brit2.gif
request+="GET /skin/base/board/view_brit2.gif HTTP/1.0\r\n";
request+="Host: cwc.ghc.ac.kr\r\n";
request+="\r\n";

//init winsock
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0)
    die_with_wserror("WSAStartup() failed");

//open socket
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    die_with_wserror("socket() failed");

//connect
memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
serveraddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddress);
serveraddr.sin_port        = htons((unsigned short) port);
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
    die_with_wserror("connect() failed");

//send request
if (send(sock, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0) != request.length())
    die_with_wserror("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");

//get response
response = "";
resp_leng= BUFFERSIZE;
while (resp_leng == BUFFERSIZE)
{
    resp_leng= recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
    if (resp_leng>0)
        response+= string(buffer).substr(0,resp_leng);
}

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("C:\\a\\example.gif");

//display response
cout << response << endl;

//get response
response = "";
resp_leng= BUFFERSIZE;
while (resp_leng == BUFFERSIZE)
{
    resp_leng= recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
    if (resp_leng>0)
        response+= string(buffer).substr(0,resp_leng);
}


//display response
cout << response << endl;


myfile << response;
myfile.close();

//disconnect
closesocket(sock);

//cleanup
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}

void die_with_error(char *errorMessage)
{
cerr << errorMessage << endl;
   exit(1);
}

void die_with_wserror(char *errorMessage)
{
    cerr << errorMessage << ": " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    exit(1);
} 

/*

It compiles and runs fine the output is: 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
ETag: W/"60-1144808550000"
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Apr 2006 02:22:30 GMT
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Length: 60
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2012 04:29:04 GMT
Connection: close

GIF89a
*/
```

What is wrong, why does it not download the full picture?

Comment: How many bytes is the picture on the server?

Comment: It's interesting then, that the server says `Content-Length: 60`.

Comment: O sorry its 60 bytes i had to go look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this loop is the problem:

```
while (resp_leng == BUFFERSIZE)
{
    resp_leng= recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
    if (resp_leng>0)
        response+= string(buffer).substr(0,resp_leng);
}
```

Calling `recv()` will give you some number of bytes from the socket, that *may be less than what you ask for*. So unlike reading from a file, asking for `BUFFERSIZE` bytes may return anywhere from 1 to `BUFFERSIZE` bytes.

Instead, loop until you get to the end of the socket:

```
while (true)
{
    resp_leng= recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
    if (resp_leng <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    response+= string(buffer,resp_leng);
}
```

Notice that I've also changed the call to the `string()` constructor on the last line of the loop (yours would work, but would do more effort than is necessary).

Comment: Reading until `recv()` returns <= 0 is the wrong way to approach this. Read until a blank line is encountered denoting the end of the response headers, and then keep reading until `Content-Length` number of bytes have been read. That is what `Content-Length` is for, assuming you even get `Content-Length` to begin with. Read RFC 2616 Section 4.4 for all the possible ways to detect the data length.

Comment: Well, that's true. I'll leave my answer as an example of how to read from a socket in a loop; parsing HTTP headers is beyond the scope of this example.

Comment: Considering that the question is specifically related to HTTP handling, your answer is the wrong way to handle it.  You really should update it to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should clear your recieve buffer out with each cycle. Put this as the first line within the loop.

ZeroMemory(buffer,sizeof(buffer));

You can get a lot of unexpected results with binary data left in the buffer.

Comment: That's not necessary and is a case of overly defensive programming. When `recv()` returns a value `n` (greater than zero), you can be certain that the first `n` bytes of the buffer have received data in them. This is one reason I suggested using `string(buffer, resp_leng)` in my answer.